# Javascript/react not running in child component - nothing clickable

Tags: reactjs, daisyui

I am using tailwind and a DaisyUI to create a page with two tabs. The parent component holds the tabs and calls a child component for the content of each tab. This works fine.

This issue is that while everything displays and styles correctly in the child components, nothing alters or updates. Even mouseover doesn't change the cursor. It is as if react/javascript isn't running in those child components. The tabs work, so I know it is running on the page. There are no errors in the console.

Parent App - working - the tabs work fine

```
import ReportDeliveryIssue from "./reportDeliveryIssue";
import ScheduleVacationStop from "./scheduleVacationStop";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function ManageMyDelivery({ tab }) {
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto mt-20">
      <div className="tabs tabs-wrapper">
        <Link
          to="/account/manageDelivery/reportDeliveryIssue"
          className={`tab tab-lg tab-lifted ${
            tab === "reportDeliveryIssue" ? "tab-active" : null
          }`}
        >
          Delivery Issue
        </Link>
        <Link
          to="/account/manageDelivery/scheduleVacationStop"
          className={`tab tab-lg tab-lifted ${
            tab === "scheduleVacationStop" ? "tab-active" : null
          }`}
        >
          Stop Delivery
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{
          border: "1px solid #CCC",
          width: "100%",
          minHeight: "50px",
          borderRadius: "0px 10px 10px 10px",
          zIndex: -99999,
          position: "relative",
          top: "-1px",
        }}
      >
        {tab === "reportDeliveryIssue" && <ReportDeliveryIssue />}
        {tab === "scheduleVacationStop" && <ScheduleVacationStop />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ManageMyDelivery;
```

Child App - not working (updated with full component)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm, useField } from "react-final-form-hooks";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";
import "react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
import ButtonWrapper from "../../../components/forms/ButtonWrapper";
import RadioWrapper from "../../../components/forms/RadioWrapper";

function ScheduleVacationStop() {
  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log("Submitting");
  };

  const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    return errors;
  };

  const { form, handleSubmit, values, pristine, submitting } = useForm({
    onSubmit,
    validate,
  });

  const savePapers = useField("savePapers", form);
  const stopPapers = useField("stopPapers", form);
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className={"container px-16 pt-16 mb-4 text-left"}>
        <div className={"text-3xl mb-8 font-bold"}>Stop Delivery</div>

        <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
          <div className="mx-4">
            <div className={"mb-8"}>
              <div className="dropdown border-2 border-solid border-neutral-400 text-gray-400 p-2 font-bold w-full text-sm">
                <label tabIndex="0" className="">
                  Stop delivery beginning
                </label>
                <div
                  tabIndex="0"
                  className="dropdown-content card card-compact w-64 p-2 shadow bg-primary text-primary-content"
                >
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h3 className="card-title">Card title!</h3>
                    <p>you can use any element as a dropdown.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <Calendar
                className={"w-full"}
                calendarType="US"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={value}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <RadioWrapper
                name={"paperStatus"}
                label={"Vacation Stop with Restart (SAVE MY PAPERS)"}
                description={
                  "The newspaper delivery will stop during the time you are away and all papers will be delivered when you resume (14 days or less)."
                }
                value={0}
                {...savePapers}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <RadioWrapper
                name={"paperStatus"}
                label={"Vacation Stop with Restart"}
                description={
                  "The newspaper delivery will stop and restart as requested."
                }
                value={1}
                {...stopPapers}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={"mb-8"}>
            <div className="dropdown border-2 border-solid border-neutral-400 text-gray-400 p-2 font-bold w-full text-sm">
              <label tabIndex="0" className="">
                Resume delivery beginning
              </label>
              <div
                tabIndex="0"
                className="dropdown-content card card-compact w-64 p-2 shadow bg-primary text-primary-content"
              >
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h3 className="card-title">Card title!</h3>
                  <p>you can use any element as a dropdown.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Calendar calendarType="US" onChange={onChange} value={value} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="divider"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="mx-12">
        <div className="alert alert-info shadow-lg px-12 text-white">
          <div>
            <span>
              To adjust an existing vacation stop, please call Customer Service
              at 214-745-8383 or 1-800-925-1500.
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="divider"></div>
      <div className={"container flex justify-between px-16 pt-2 pb-8"}>
        <div className={"uppercase text-sm text-sky-500 font-bold"}>
          <Link to="/account/dashboard">Return to Dashboard</Link>
        </div>
        <ButtonWrapper
          buttonType="submit"
          handleClick={() => handleSubmit(values)}
          buttonText={"Submit"}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ScheduleVacationStop;
```

Comment: Your "Child App" does not appear to be in a function? Is this an over simplification for the sake of the question? Or is that actually what you're using?

Comment: We kinda need to see the code of the child component since that is likely where the problem is

Comment: Assuming the above is not the problem, I would debug this by adding a `useEffect` that console logs on mount and unmount. `React.useEffect(() => {console.log('mount'); return () => console.log('unmount')},[]);`. My guess is that something at a higher level is causing your component to be destroyed each render and that is why interaction has no affect.

Comment: Good suggestion on useEffect test. I tried it and it works correctly. It shows the child mounting when the tab is selecting and unmounting when another is selected

Answer (score 0):

So, this was an odd situation. There was a div that held the tabs and a div that held all tab content. I placed a condition on each child component to only be shown when the appropriate tab was selected.

To make the active tab display correctly and get rid of the border line at the top of the content box, I made the content's position relative and bumped it up one pixel. Apparently, this is what was causing the problem.

The solution was to remove that and bump the tabs down one pixel.

Not sure if this is a problem with Daisy or what.